# Code review my buggy bubble sort code

Tags: python, sorting

I wrote this code for bubble sort, it shows this error:

```
File "bubble.py", line 6
    for i in range(0,n)
```

Can anyone tell me how to use the `range` function so that I can take input `n` from the user and loop through it?

```
print "Enter n"
n = raw_input()
print "enter elements"
a = []
for i in range(0,n)
    temp = raw_input()
    a[i].append(temp)

for i in range(0,n)
    for j in range(0,n-1)
        if a[j]>a[j+1]
            temp = a[j]
            a[j] = a[j+1]
            a[j+1] = temp


for i in range(0,n)
    print a[i]
```

Comment: you can just use `range(n)`, the 0 is implicit

Comment: Please read literally any Python tutorial. For example, the official one: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing colons at the end of each line with `if` and `for`:

```
for j in range(0,n-1):
#                    ↑ THIS
    if a[j]>a[j+1]:
    #             ↑ THIS
```

and so on.

Also, `raw_input()` returns a string. You need to convert it to integer:

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

The same goes for the other place you use `raw_input()` -- there the situation is a bit worse in that the program won't fail but your code will quietly sort the elements [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) rather than numerically.

The following are not errors but would help make your code more idiomatic:

- `range(0,n)` can be written as `range(n)`;
- swapping `a[j]` and `a[j+1]` can be written as `a[j], a[j+1] = a[j+1], a[j]`.

Answer (score 7):

Python uses colons to start blocks, each for, if, while, etc needs a : at the end

```
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n-1):
        if a[j]>a[j+1]:
```

---

Additional problems:

```
n = raw_input()
```

`n` will be a `str`, you need to convert it to an int like so:

```
n = int(raw_input())
```

---

With `range`, 0 is an implicit start, using `range(n)` is the same as `range(0, n)`

---

In your first loop you have

```
temp = raw_input()
a[i].append(temp)
```

but `a` is a list with nothing in it, you are using it like a list of lists.  instead I believe you just mean to append to `a`, and again you must convert the value to a number

```
temp = float(raw_input())
a.append(temp)
```

which could also just be

```
a.append(float(raw_input()))
```

---

The raw_input function takes a string which it prints as a user prompt.  You can shorten your first two lines to

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter n"))
```

---

Your last `for` loop is very c-style.  You should prefer a more pythonic "for-each" loop.  don't iterate over indices, iterate over elements, change the last loop to

```
for e in a:
    print e
```

You might also want to just `print a` directly.

---

Finally, it's worth mentioning that python has a sort function in it already.  If your task is not to write a sort function, then just use that by doing

```
a.sort()
```

after reading everything in from the user.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of mistakes in your code. First the missing colons after,

```
for i in range(0,n): 
for j in range(0,n-1):
if a[j]>a[j+1]:
```

Next you need to cast `raw_input() as int(raw_input())`

Again is the line `a[i].append() should be changed to a.append()`

Here is modified code

```
print "Enter n"
n = int(raw_input())
print "enter elements"
a = []
for i in range(0,n):
    temp = int(raw_input())
    a.append(temp)

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n-1):
        if a[j]>a[j+1]:
            temp = a[j]
            a[j] = a[j+1]
            a[j+1] = temp


for i in range(0,n):
    print a[i]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged as they are of very little utility.  You should explain *how* the code works and attempt to clear up any misunderstandings OP has, rather than just hand them a solution.

Comment: this code is also wrong.  you haven't converted the input from the user to a number in the first loop, so it will perform a string comparison which is almost certainly not what OP wants.

Comment: Ok Ryan i must tell u that it's not written anywhere in the question that u need to sort integers. But still i have made modifications.

Comment: Your explanations still don't really explain much,  why must one use `int(raw_input())`, what is the problem with `a[i].append()`?  You haven't made some changes that would be seem obvious such as `range(n)` instead of `range(0, n)`.  the last loop is clumsy, the swapping could be done cleanly in one line.  If you want to post a big code block, made it a model.  And yes I'm aware that it doesn't specify integers (which is why I actually used `float`) but again, I doubt that OP is trying to sort strings.

Comment: Ok i got your points. I will try to be accurate next time. Thanks.